# Wordpress Error Missing Argument

Tags: errors

I've just started recieving the following error on my WP site, when I publish a page update:

Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /home/greenfin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/auto-image-field/auto-image-field.php on line 98 and defined in/home/greenfin/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 992

The page still publishes correctly but I have to back/forward out of the error screen to see anything. I'm concerned it may cause ongoing issues. Any ideas on how to update?

Comment: Next time please [search for that message](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Missing%20argument%202%20for%20wpdb%3A%3Aprepare()).

Answer (score 0):

That plugin is using outdated code. `$wpdb->prepare` used to allow the second parameter to be omitted, though using `prepare` without it never really made since. As of 3.5 [the second parameter is required](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks).

You will need to update the plugin, if there is an update, or hack the plugin yourself which is prone to cause headaches unless you flat out fork it and maintain your own branch (which could be a lot of work).